# Very Ample sheaves

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, schemes, coherent-sheaves, projective-varieties

Let $X$ be the non singular cubic curve $y^2z=x^3-xz^2$ in projective space of dimension 2. Let $L$ be the invertible sheaf $L(P_0)$. How does $L(P_0)$ not being generated by global sections imply that there is a point $Q$ which is equivalent to $P_0$?

I am having trouble in understanding this. It is Example(7.6.3) on Page 156 of Hartshorne.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Given the question cannot be understood without the text in the image link, I'm voting to close it for missing context.

Comment: @Garg12 - It seems your equation should be the following: $y^2z=x(x-z)(x+z)=x^3-xz^2$.

Answer (score 2):

The text says

> If $L(P_0)$ were generated by global sections, then $P_0$ would be linearly equivalent to some other point $Q \in X$.

This goes as follows: Suppose $L(P_0)$ is generated by global sections. Then there is a global section $s \in \Gamma(X, L(P_0))$ which generated $L(P_0)$ at the point $P_0$. The effective Cartier divisor of zeroes
$$D = (s)_0 = \{\, P \in X \,|\, s_P \in \mathfrak m_P L(P_0) \,\}$$
is then linearly equivalent to $P_0$ by Proposition 7.7. I claim that $D$ consists of one point only, which has multiplicity $1$. To see that, consider the global section $s^{\otimes 3} \in L(3P_0) = \mathcal O_X(1)$. Since it is a global section of a very ample sheaf (which is very ample with respect to the embedding $X \subset \mathbb P^2$), the associated Cartier divisor $(s^{\otimes 3})_0 = 3D$ is linearly equivalent to a Cartier divisor obtained by intersecting $X$ with a line in $\mathbb P^2$. Hence we get $$3 \deg D = \deg (s^{\otimes 3})_0 = \deg X = 3,$$
and thus $\deg D = 1$. As $D$ is effective, there is a point $Q \in X$ such that $D = 1 \cdot Q$.

Comment: Right hand side equality of D=(s)_0 =? is not clear .

Comment: @Garg12 Yeah, that was a bit sloppy. For the correct definition of $(s)_0$ see the paragraph in Hartshorne before Prop 7.7. But if you look at the Weil divisor associated to $(s)_0$ it will consist of such points $P \in X$ where $s$ does not generate $L(P_0)$ (i.e. $s$ vanishes in $k(P)$) , counted with the vanishing multiplicity.

Comment: got it, thankyou.

Comment: @Garg12 If this solves your question, you could accept the answer ;)

Comment: @ red_trumpet How degree $(s)^{\otimes 3}_o$ =deg X?

Comment: @Garg12 This is because $(s^{\otimes 3})_0$ is linearly equivalent to a divisor $D'$ which is obtained by intersecting $X$ with a line $L \subset \mathbb P^2$ (actually it could be that $(s^{\otimes 3})_0 = D'$, but I'm not too sure). By Bezout's theorem, $\deg D' = \deg X$.

Comment: I not understand this point